How configure data source programmatically and inject that data source to required entity classes and using panache to those entity classes?
I am able to create the data source programmatically but when I am querying with panache method it is not working. How achieve this
I need to add panache to the entity classes and repository classes for  programmatically created data sources.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to add panache features to programatically created data source
